# Upgrading .NET Core version of a C# project from Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the project, I get this error

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (*.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '2.2.7'
> path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcoreapp2.2/Microsoft.CSharp.dll'

Comment: You have an error (probably because you don't have the mentioned runtime version 2.2 deployed), and you have a question (how to upgrade from .NET Core 2 to .NET Core 3). That's two separate questions, which do you want answered and what have you tried? Or do you mean that you did upgrade, but now get that error? Then recompile.

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 went out of support a couple of years ago. The oldest supported version is .NET Core 3.1 which will go out of support in 1 year. The current LTS version is .NET (Core) 6, which will be supported for the next 3 years. You can find out more about .NET Core's lifetime policies at [.NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

Comment: To fix this problem you need to change your project to target NET Core 3.1 or 6, recompile and install the corresponding runtime on the target machine. Another possibility with .NET Core 3.1 and later is to create a [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) . The published application will include the necessary runtime files so you don't have to install the runtime separately. This adds about 60MB to a .NET 6 application

Comment: If your application uses EF Core, expect some breaking changes as client-side evaluation was disabled in EF Core 3.1

Comment: @CodeCaster The problem is that I don't know how to upgrade the project from ubuntu cli. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Change the .csproj file to target a different framework.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes I did that but I get the error mentioned above in the deps.json file :/